# Не конкатенируется 'FSMContextProxy' с 'int'

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram

Я пишу бота "угадай число" для телеграма. Я хочу добавить команду choice по которой юзер будет писать любое число и бот будет загадывать свое число от 1 до числа, загаданного юзером. Но при рандомном выборе в строке  `t = random.randint(1, num)` вылазит ошибка

```
return self.randrange(a, b+1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'FSMContextProxy' and 'int'
```

Код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['choice'])
async def choice(message: types.Message):
    await Form.num.set()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите целое число до которого я загадаю свое число. Примечания: введите только целое число. Введите число не менее 50, иначе победа не будет засчитана. При вводе числа >= 100 будет засчитано 2 балла.')
    
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.num)
async def num(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as num:
        num['number'] = int(message.text)
    await state.finish()
    t = random.randint(1, num)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я загадал число от 1 до ' + num + '. Теперь попробуй отгадать его.')
```

Пробовал сделать так:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['choice'])
async def choice(message: types.Message):
    await Form.num.set()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите целое число до которого я загадаю свое число. Примечания: введите только целое число. Введите число не менее 50, иначе победа не будет засчитана. При вводе числа >= 100 будет засчитано 2 балла.')
    global num
    async with state.proxy() as num:
        num['number'] = int(message.text)
    await state.finish()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.num)
async def num(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    t = random.randint(1, num)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я загадал число от 1 до ' + num + '. Теперь попробуй отгадать его.')
```

Тогда ошибка

```
return self.randrange(a, b+1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'
```

Если же сделать

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['choice'])
async def choice(message: types.Message, state = FSMContext):
    await Form.num.set()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите целое число до которого я загадаю свое число. Примечания: введите только целое число. Введите число не менее 50, иначе победа не будет засчитана. При вводе числа >= 100 будет засчитано 2 балла.')
    global num
    async with state.proxy() as num:
        num['number'] = int(message.text)
    await state.finish()
    t = random.randint(1, num)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я загадал число от 1 до ' + num + '. Теперь попробуй отгадать его.')
```

Тогда

```
num['number'] = int(message.text)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '/choice'
```

Comment: `num['number']` и `random.randint(1, num)` - ничего не смущает? Может тогда уж `random.randint(1, num['number'])`? Да и потом, `num` то функция, то переменная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    async with state.proxy() as num:
                                ^^^
        num['number'] = int(message.text)
        ^^^
    await state.finish()
    t = random.randint(1, num)
                          ^^^
```

Здесь у вас `num` - это то, что выдаёт `state.proxy()`.

```
async def num(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
          ^^^
    t = random.randint(1, num)
                          ^^^
```

А здесь `num` - это название функции, начатой строкой выше.

Вы сначала назовите всё как-то по-разному: функции одними именами, переменные другими, прокси всякие назовите `proxy`. А то у вас несколько разных сущностей, и все они называются `num`. При этом питон не различает сущности по способу обращения к ним, в нём не может быть одновременно и функция и переменная с одним именем, вернее они могут быть, но их названия будут друг-друга "перекрывать" и у вас будут очень странные ошибки. Для начала разведите эти все сущности по разным осмысленным именам, а там и разберётесь, где у вас что.